# Retrieve visitor's bookmarks

Tags: php, javascript, bookmarks

I'm working on a website where there is a need to know the visitors' bookmarks. For security reasons the visitors could put a login and a password.

I have no idea on how to proceed and the languages I could use to do this (JavaScript or PHP would be great).

Someone has any idea or already done something similar?

Comment: I haven't really got a clue but I assume this would be impossible. Just think about all the privacy issues alone

Comment: I know that's why the website could ask for a login and a password but you may be right.

Comment: Even if there *was* possible it definitely wouldn't be with PHP.  PHP is a server side language and doesn't run in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you'll have to create a browser [plug-in](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_%28computing%29)/[add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/?browse=featured)/[extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/?hl=en) and have the user install it and give it permission to access their bookmarks; or similarly with a [signed script](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/components/signed-scripts.html). For obvious reasons, there's nothing you can do in a plain old web page that will give you this information.

Comment: You could then have that extension send the list of bookmarks to your site via xmlHttpRequest();

Answer (score 3):

You have to ask the users to export their bookmarks to a file and them have them upload that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pull anonymous users' bookmarks.